# Replace white space with another character after calling function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, file-io

I need help getting declared string function to change white space of input file to a specific character.

```
if (infile.fail())
{
    cout << "The file doesn't exist";
    exit(-1);
}
else
{
    numBooks = readFile (infile, magSub, 260);

    for (i=0; i<numBooks; i++)
    {
        cout << "Last Name: " << magSub[i].lastName << endl;
        cout << "First Name: " << magSub[i].firstName << endl;
        cout << "Street Address: " << magSub[i].address << endl;
        cout << "City: " << magSub[i].city << endl;
        cout << "State or Province: " << magSub[i].state << endl;
        cout << "Country: " << magSub[i].country << endl << endl;
        cout << "Zip or Postal Code: " << magSub[i].zip << endl;
        cout << "Expiration Date: " << magSub[i].expDate << endl;
        cout << "Subscriber Number: " << magSub[i].subNum << endl << endl;
    }
    writeFile(outfile, magSub, numBooks);
 }
}

void fillSpace (string &expDate)
{
 for (int i=0; expDate.length(); i++)
 {
    if (isspace(expDate[i]))
        expDate[i] = '0';
 }
}
```

I have the function declared above main. I know I need to call the function but I can't get it to change the white spaces.

Comment: You aren't calling your space-changing function.

Comment: I am not sure how to call the function to make it work.  I have tried calling it but it does not change the file.

Comment: So do you think *not* calling it will help?

Comment: `for (int i=0; expDate.length(); i++)` should be `for (int i=0; i < expDate.length(); i++)`

Comment: @OP can you please show the definition of whatever class `magSub` is. It matters whether the variables are `string`s or char arrays.

Comment: you must call the function

Answer (score 0):

In your code for `fillSpace`, you are not checking for the end of string condition. You should use `i<expDate.length()` for checking the end of string.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed the check condition in `for` loop of `fillSpace` function.

`for (int i=0; i < expDate.length(); i++)`

And for calling the function
you have to declare a string which will store the string from the `magSub[i].expDate`.

and then pass that string to the function `fillSpace`.

After that you will get the string with replaced `char space with '0'`.

`cout << "Expiration Date: " << magSub[i].expDate << endl;`

please use the following code:

```
    string temp = magSub[i].expDate; // copy the string to the temp string/char array

    fillSpace (temp); // Missing Line for function call 

    cout << "Expiration Date: " << temp << endl; // replace line with
```

Hope
this will Help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help...it crashes when i put that line of code in.

Comment: @user3546210 What is the datatype of `expDate`?

Comment: I have a struct Magazine (string expDate);

Comment: @user3546210 can you please tell me the error message?

Comment: @user3546210 Please check the answer. I have edited now... Hope this will work fine... please try it

Comment: I get windows popup saying program stop working and then processed returned 255(0xFF).

Comment: Please don't use `strcpy`. That is for use on C-style strings which are stored in char arrays. Your suggested code doesn't compile.

Comment: @MattMcNabb to compile this you have to include 'string.h' in your code.

Comment: ...and fix the mistakes in it.  You need to declare `temp` for a start